# Google maps route with coordinates

Tags: google-maps

please may you help I need to up load a routes on Google maps different colour routes and animate them if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following javascript code:
Note that lat_lng is array of latitude and longitude.

```
        //Initialize the Path Array.  
    var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

    //Getting the Direction Service.  
    var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    //Set the Path Stroke Color.  
    var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map, strokeColor: '#4986E7', strokeOpacity: 0.8, strokeWeight: 2
    });

    //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP.  
    for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
        if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
            var src = lat_lng[i];
            var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
            path.push(src);
            poly.setPath(path);
            service.route({
                origin: src,
                destination: des,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function (result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    alert("Invalid location.");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”. thanks alot and can I use the same stoke color on the gmap library in c# for a windows form?

Comment: Check out this link. [link](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Demo.WindowsForms/Forms/MainForm.cs)